# Global Variable returning Null

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a program with Two windows (Both are controlled from the same Class File) and a Global Variable named `PersonName1`, `Window A` and `Window B`. On `Window A` there are 2 buttons, One which:

```
-(IBAction)setPersonName:(id)sender
{
    PersonName1 = @"Tom";
}
```

And the other which changes from Window A to Window B

On Window B there is a button which does:

```
- (IBAction)loadNames:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",PersonName1);
}
```

The problem is whenever the screen changes, and when I click the button on Window B, the NSlog returns **(null)** instead of **"Tom"**. What is causing this?

*More information from comment:*

`PersonName1` is declared in the main ViewController.h file as so:

```
NSString* PersonName1;
```

and a property in that file aswell.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *PersonName1;
```

This is then synthesised in the ViewController.m file. Both the IBActions listed in the question are also both in the ViewController.m file.

Comment: where did you define `PersonName1`?

Comment: what do you call a "window"? UIView? UIWindow? or a UIViewController?

Comment: What's probably happening is that your global is getting eaten by the autorelease pool popping. Unfortunately, this is one of the reasons why its a bad idea to use global variables in objective C. What you may want to consider doing is using a singleton class to hold the variable, and then having a globally available mechanism like a class method on that singleton to change the variable.

Comment: We can't answer this question without knowing the declaration of `PersonName1`.

Comment: Hey all thanks for the replies,

PersonName1 is declared in the main ViewController.h file as so:

    NSString*PersonName1;


and a property in that file aswell

    @property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *PersonName1;


This is then synthesised in the ViewController.m file.


(Both the IBActions listed in the question are also both in the ViewController.m file)

Thanks.

Comment: try with  NSLog(@"%@",self.PersonName1);

Comment: Did you declare the variable as an ivar (inside the @interface curly braces part)? Or did you really define it in the header as a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you did not pass value to one view controller into another view controller.

ex:
**first view controller**
have global value as NSString *nameString.
like below

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *PersonName1;
```

and 
**second view controller**
 it have global string as NSString *nameString
like below

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *PersonName1;
```

when you want pass value to one view controller into another mean.do like below

```
 SecoundViewController *SVC = [[SecoundViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil]; 
SVC.PersonName1 = self.PersonName1;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:SVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you have to click first button on the first window to allocate value to PersonName1. If you didnt click first button but clicked second button instead then it will return null because declaration on PersonName1 will only happen if you click first button.

Comment: The NSlog returns NULL when I click the first button first, then the 2nd button.